# Alsa hardware volume with PulseAudio

Tags: linux, debian, kde, alsa, pulse-audio

Before installing pulseaudio, I was able to control volume for the front (meaning on the front panel, the "headphone" jack) and rear (meaning on the back panel, the "line out" jack) separately.

When I installed pulseaudio, it became possible to control volume for each playing process separately, but the individual controls for outputs disappeared.

While the `default` device in alsa now routes via pulseaudio, the `sysdefault` device provides access to the hardware. But kmix does not seem to let me show them now. Is there any way to beat kmix into showing the `sysdefault` device too? Or something else X-based that would not fight with kmix too much?

The system is Debian Jessie (testing) amd64, updated, KDE version 4:4.13.3-1.

Comment: PulseAudio does react to jack-plug events (if supported by the hw). Have you pluged something into the jacks' in question?

Comment: @paradoxon: Both jacks _always_ have something connected and do play. But sometimes I want to lower volume of the loudspeakers (that can't be easily pulled out) without affecting the headphones.

Comment: @paradoxon: Besides, both jacks behave as single device. They just have separate volume controls.

Comment: Yes. If they have separate devices they technically should have separate volume controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a bunch of other mixers available in Debian. On console the curses-based `alsamixer` from [`alsa-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/alsa-utils) can switch between devices, but the ones advertised as X11 counterparts don't seem to or can only select device on command-line. The only mixer I found being able to switch devices is [`qasmixer`](https://packages.debian.org/qasmixer). It's statusbar icon is worse than the kmix one, so I am keeping kmix for the soft volume and only use qasmixer if I need to tweak the independent output levels.

Comment: Try `pavucontrol` (version 2, 1 is deprecated)  unfortunately it is a gtk based utility so it will look a bit ugly on kde but it is pretty powerful. You can find the package in Debian repos.

Comment: @paradoxon: I tried pavucontrol, it has "output devices" tab, but it behaves weirdly. It shows only one (stereo) volume control which control the output master and a "Port" switch and when I switch it, it changes the volume to some value. Of both outputs the same way.

Comment: @paradoxon: (styling is the least of my concerns and it is possible to apply the same style to both Gtk and Qt if desired)